# Show Segue not entering navigation stack. No back button appears on the View Controller, and it is sliding up from bottom not the left side

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to figure out why my show segues aren't entering the destination View Controller into the navigation stack.

1. I have a root View Controller embedded in a Navigation controller.
2. I run a show segue from that VC to another view controller
3. The new view controller does not have a back button and is sliding up from the bottom, not the left side.

pic of the vc, notice there is no back button. You can slide the screen down to make it pop back to the previous view controller.

[image]

Online I have found that this may be because that both the original and destination view controllers could be in their own navigation controller. However, there is no indication that the destination View Controller is within a different navigation stack.

Im looking for help on 1. Is there an easy solution to make sure the view controller gets shown correctly?
2. Is there a way to tell which navigation controllers are attached to each view controller?

Here is a pic of the navigation stack:

[image]

Comment: How are you presenting the new VC? `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` or `present(_:animated:completion:)`?

Comment: I'm using performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)

Comment: Please see the segue options on the storyboard. There is some mismatch in the segue options while you connect the controllers on storyboard. In iOS 13, some view controllers are displaying as a present. So please verify at your end. When you connect the storyboard the value of segue is "Show" or something else.

Comment: The segue I'm using is the one called Push(show). All of the other segue options are also giving me the exact same results

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the issue.

When initializing the main view controller, I segued to the main view controller rather than the attached navigation controller. This in turn didn't register the attached navigation controller.